# XSLT output formatting: keep line breaks, remove indent

Tags: xml, xslt, indentation, line-breaks

Here's my XML:

```
<doc>
  <article>
    <texte>
      <notes>-</notes>
      <content>
        <title>T 1</title>
        <argument>Arg 1</argument>
        <p>Paragraph 1.1</p>
        <p>Paragraph 1.2</p>
        <p>Paragraph <i>1.3</i></p>
        <short-author>FB</short-author>
      </content>
      <notes>-</notes>
      <content>
        <title>T2</title>
        <p>Paragraph 2.1</p>
        <short-author>JD</short-author>
      </content>
      <notes>-</notes>
      <content>
        <title>T3</title>
        <argument>Arg 3</argument>
        <p>Paragraph 3.1</p>
        <short-author>NC</short-author>
      </content>
    </texte>
  </article>
</doc>
```

This is the XSL (thanks Dimitre):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/> 
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>


<xsl:template match="//comment()"/>

<xsl:template match="@class" />

  <xsl:template match="node()[not(self::doc|self::texte|self::author|self::style|self::span)]|@*" >
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::author)]|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>



</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So far so good. I'd like to

- preserve the line-breaks and
- remove the indentation

When I set output indent to "yes", I get both, line-breaks and indents.
When I set output indent to "no", I get none.

Thank you!

Comment: Which XSLT processor are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't strip and don't indent, but transform white space text nodes to a line break, as in

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="comment()"/>

<xsl:template match="@class" />

  <xsl:template match="node()[not(self::doc|self::texte|self::author|self::style|self::span)]|@*" >
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::author)]|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()[not(normalize-space())]">
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

then the result is hopefully what you want.

Comment: Thanks, that worked, but I didn't think it to its end. Any idea how I could selectively omit a line break, e.g. between `</p>` and `<short-author>`?

Comment: Further, this method creates empty lines where nodes have been omitted (`<xsl:template match="node()[not(self::doc|self::texte|self::author|self::style|self::span)]|@*" >`). Any idea how to get rid of them?

Comment: As for your first comment, if you add e.g. `<xsl:template match="text()[not(normalize-space())][preceding-sibling::node()[1][self::p]][following-sibling::node()[1][self::short-author]]`, then white space between a `p` and `short-author` would be removed.